# How to solve Incorrect padding in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I just installed [`clearcache`](https://pypi.org/project/django-clearcache/) package in Django and after refresh my website i got `Incorrect padding` error, here is the [error code](https://prnt.sc/u7y08g), so please let me know how i can solve this issues. I research a lot about it but i did not found  `base64.py` file in my file structure.

Comment: Please add the full traceback in text. See [this help document](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). The symptom is in [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), but the root of the problem is earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete cookie-files from your browser.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050

It's realy worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've grasped the solutions here but I had this problem when trying to render 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

I solved it in the end by upgrading my Django version from 3.0.10 to 3.1.1.

**pip3 install django==3.1.1**

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when running 'python3 manage.py runserver' without first activating the virtualenv. I can't say what the specific issue is as I don't know, but once I activated the virtualenv and THEN issued the runserver command, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed Django using pip3.

```
pip3 install django
```

and I'm using python 2 instead of python 3, so I got this error because of the mismatched version of pip and python.

So please check the version of python and pip. I Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error on a local dev version of Django 2.28, after a lot of manipulation of other versions in git worktrees, etc. Following advice seen elsewhere, deleted all django_session records in the db, and that fixed it at least in my case.

Answer (score -1):

That package is 8 years old and incompatible with current Django. Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/

Comment: i install this package...https://pypi.org/project/django-clearcache/

Comment: I know, its not maintained anymore and its unusable. As you can see the last update is 8 years ago.

Comment: it's release data is `Released: Jan 21, 2020`

Comment: You said that you added to your installed apps `clear_cache` but I can see from the documentation of this that its `clearcache` could it be that?

Comment: update my question, Please let me know the solution for this

Comment: He's using Django 3.0.x (see error), linking to just the general caching documentation doesn't highlight the compatibility problem. Plus, linking without summary is not useful.

Comment: His original post was about `clear_cache` which is another package not the one that he has linked now. As you see, he is looking for a `base64.py` file which clearly indicates that he doesn't know what he is doing. It's fine we all learn that's why I linked the documentation. On top of that I tried all of that locally, following the documentation and everything works correctly. If he provides more information about the issue such as code or did he followed the django-clearcache docs at all I cannot do anything else.